# How can you ban a user from application's discussion board?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, block

I can figure out how to ban users from most pages' discussion boards using the Graph API, but I can't find any way to do this for application pages. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking how to ban a user programmatically, right?

Comment: Looking to ban trouble makers from the Discussion Boards. Used to be able to do it by clicking on "Report" for the post, mark as spam/etc, and then presented with option to ban and remove all posts but can no longer do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use old api calls with new Graph API

You have to use this API Call: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.banUsers/

And here is how you can use it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: I used to have that set up but for some reason it wasn't working, maybe I need to revisit that could, just figured that it may be deprecated since I used to ban through that before it was enabled in the Discussion Boards. Thanks for the reply.